# Dealing with multiple Javascript IF statements

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Is it possible to put multiple IF statements in Javascript? If so, I'm having a fair amount of trouble with the statement below. I was wondering if you can put another IF statement in between **if (data == 'valid') AND else**? I want to add another **if data =='concept')** between the two.

```
if (data == 'valid') {
    $("#file").slideUp(function () {
        $("#file").before('<div class="approvedMessage">WIN WIN WIN!</div>');
        setTimeout(ApprovedProof, 5000);
    });

    function ApprovedProof() {
        $("#file").slideDown();
        $('.approvedMessage').fadeOut();
    }

}
else {

    $("#file").slideUp(function () {
        $("#file").before('<div class="deniedMessage">NO NO NO!</div>');
        setTimeout(DeniedProof, 5000);
    });

    function DeniedProof() {
        $("#file").slideDown();
        $('.deniedMessage').fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean an `else if` clause?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should consider using anonymous functions in your timers.

Comment: As I am reviewing it as I type!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
if(data == 'valid') {
    // block 1
} else if (data == 'concept') {
    // block 2
} else {
    // block 3
}
```

Comment: I'm too tired to think. I put elseif, instead of else if. Thanks!

Comment: Whereas it was making elseif a function instead of the preset function "else if". :(

Answer (score 4):

If you intend for the data variable to hold many different values, you may find the switch statement a better fit for your needs:

```
switch(data)
{
  case "valid":
     //stuff
     break;
  case "concept":
     //stuff
     break;
  case "this": case "that":
     //more stuff
     break;
  default:
     break;
}
```

Note that break statements after each case, that multiple case statements can be used per condition, and that there is a catch-call default case that will fire if nothing else matched.  The switch statement is nothing more than a more concise version of the If statement.

Comment: I'm going to attempt this method, just to see how it runs.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `else if`

```
if (data == "valid") {
    // stuff here
} else if (data == "concept") {
    // more stuff
} else {
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to the question, but Joey asked for clarification of using an anonymous function with his timer:

```
if (data == 'valid') {
    $("#file").slideUp(function () {
        $("#file").before('<div class="approvedMessage">WIN WIN WIN!</div>');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#file").slideDown();
            $('.approvedMessage').fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what the advantage to adding more functions would be?

Comment: That's not adding more functions, it's declaring the function where it's used as an 'anonymous function', aka a lambda or closure. There's no point in declaring it separately and giving it a name since you only use it right in that spot.  Also, closures have some unique and powerful properties regarding variable scope which are very important in advanced JavaScript, but that's a whole other issue!